# How to close connection from mongodb to springboot once connection stablish

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, caching

I am using springboot and mongodb. I am doing exception handling for my all the controllers. To check the exception I want to disable connection between my application to mongodb so I comment all the properties of mongodb from application.properties file like bellow and then restart the application

```
#Local MongoDB config
#spring.data.mongodb.database=AlokTestingSpringboot
##spring.data.mongodb.username=
##spring.data.mongodb.password=
#spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

but still connection has not over. My save and get url are still saving and getting not from mongodb but somewhere else. It may be somewhere from cache because when I run query directly in mongodb console then data has not submitted. Someone can help me, how to close connection from mongodb to springboot

Comment: Did you clean/rebuild before restarting?  But why use this manual approach? Consider writing a unit test for repeatability, and inject a mock Service/Repository/etc which can be set up to throw whatever exception is needed to test the exception handling.

Comment: Yes.  I check clean restart but still the same problem.  I closed my mongodb service from my machine then my application started giving 500 error.  So I just want to know whether any cache used by spring boot for adding and getting data?